# JavaScript+Mocha+Chai. Why do my test always pass?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I have index.html file with '*Hello world!*' text in h1:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my index.test.js:

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import fs from 'fs';

describe('index.html', () => {
    it("should say 'Hello world!'", () => {
        // read file content to variable
        const index = fs.readFileSync('./src/index.html', "utf-8");

        // pass this variable to jsdom:
        jsdom.env(index, function(err, window) {
            const h1 = window.document.getElementByTagName('h1')[0];   // read our h1
            expect(h1.innerHTML).to.equal("Helloooooooo World!");      //<---- passed
            done();
            window.close();
        });
    })
})
```

I save all and run it like this:

```
"test": "mocha --reporter progress buildScripts/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.test.js\""
```

and it always reports "Passed".

[image]

I can even comment `expect` string, and it passes too oO

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to declare `done` as an argument to `it`.

```
it('Does x', (done) => {
  someAsyncFunc((err, result) => {
    done()
  })
})
```

By declaring that 1st argument you essentially tell mocha to wait until `done` is called, otherwise it just considers it a synchronous test

Therefore it won't wait for your `expect` calls to run and will prematurely consider the test as succesful.

From [Mocha's docs](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code):

> Simply invoke the callback when your test is complete. By adding a callback (usually named done) to it(), Mocha will know that it should wait for this function to be called to complete the test.

Comment: Ahh.. Thank You much! Now it works like a charm! + I've also found that there  should be 'getElement_s_ByTagName' :)

Comment: Love you for this answer. Passing done as an argument doesn't sound too logic for me

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
it("should say 'Hello world!'", (done) => {
```